# content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response, in spite of all cors requests seemingly allowed

Tags: .net-core, cors

I have 2 dot net core applications.  One being used as an API server and the other as an angular web client.

Just to get things working for the sake of getting work done, I had put this in the ConfigureServices method of my API server's startup.  I believed this would just allow any requests..

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(ALL_ORIGINS,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("*");
                });
            });
```

It seemed to be working but all of my requests were GETs.  The first time I tried to POST I got the error

> Request header field content-type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Figuring I had a crappy temporary solution in place on the API server I put the same "*" cors policy in place in the angular web client server and it didn't help.

I'm not sure what I need to do here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
```

That should work at least in .NET Core 2.1

Comment: Thank, you, I added AllowAnyHeader and the resolved that issue.

What is a good resource to use to understand what the correct solution would be for production?

Comment: I have to say I don't remember. Probably MS docs. I just copied the above code from one of my own projects.

Comment: Also add it in the following order in the Configure method

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllers();
});